# This code has error at Status InitStack(Sqstack& s) i try to change & and its correct but adding more error again

Tags: c

This code has error at Status InitStack(Sqstack& s) and i dont know expected error at that section error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token

```
typedef int Status;

typedef struct Sqstack
{
    elemtype* base;
    elemtype* top;
    int stacksize;
}Sqstack;

Status InitStack(Sqstack& s)
{
    s.base=(elemtype*)malloc(inisize*sizeof(elemtype));
    if (!s.base) exit(luber);
    s.top=s.base;
    s.stacksize=inisize;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: there are no references `&` in pure c, are you using c++?

Comment: oh yeah thanks i forget that